# showing only rows which has is_active as true unless user searches for false rows in ROR active scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I have a table with a column is_active which takes boolean parameter . So I want to list only the rows which have is_active as true by default unless user searches for the false value rows . Is there any way that I can achieve this . I tried **"conditions_for_collection "** method but that shows only true rows and when you search for false it shows no rows found . I tried **condition_for_is_active_column** also but no luck .

```
def conditions_for_collection
   ['is_active = ?', true]
  end
  
  def condition_for_is_active_column(column, value, like_pattern)
    case value
      when 'true'
        ['is_active = ?', true]
      when 'false'
        ['is_active = ?', false]
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hey @shruthi Can you Do some thing like this result = ModelName.where('is_active = ?', value)

Comment: @shruthi chowdhary: You need to show how you're using those methods at the controller level. Something like `@collection = Model.where(is_active: params[:is_active].presence || true)` should work.

Comment: @000723-weict , in the condition_for_is_active_column function ?

Comment: @Arctodus , where and how should i use it ?

Answer (score 0):

try to help you.
Have you tried using default_scope?
Docs here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class
And you can use ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value) Instead of case "true"
Example:

```
def condition_for_is_active_column(column, value, like_pattern)
  ['is_active = ?', ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)]
end
```

Bollean cast format: 1 => true, "true" => true, nil => false. And other. Hope, it is help you

Comment: still for false search it is returning no rows .

Comment: hello @shruthichowdhary can you provide more information on this as it seems your intent is different then what you expect here.